# OpenCV failing to Load Mat Android

Tags: java, android, c++, opencv, android-ndk

I have been working on an Image processing app and recently started using OpenCV because it is easy. According to OpenCV documentation it is recommended to use static initialization so that the system imports all your libs automatically, but it does not seem to be so automatic anymore, according to the documentation I was suppose to 
1. download the OpenCV SKD
2. download Android SDK and NDK
3. import OpenCV project to my android project that is in OpenCV/sdk/java/lint.imi file which I did and it imported successfully
 Then I had to statically link my Java project with the imported OpenCV java files with

```
    static {
     if (!OpenCVLoader.initDebug()) {
       // Handle initialization error
      }
    }
```

before onCreate but still got the error `UnsatisfiedLinkError` then looked up online and was advised to initialize it like

```
private BaseLoaderCallback mOpenCVCallBack = new BaseLoaderCallback(this) {
    @Override
    public void onManagerConnected(int status) {
    switch (status) {
   case LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS:
    {
    Log.i(TAG, "OpenCV loaded successfully");
    // Create and set View
      setContentView(R.layout.main);
   } break;
   default:
   {
  super.onManagerConnected(status);
    } break;
   }
  }
 };`
```

but either way I got the error, before I was using OpenCV 3.0.0 but downgraded to 2.4.11 but no change, anyone who has had this problem to help me, thanks in advance.

Comment: did you load .so file using System.loadLibrary ?

Comment: no, I did not do any code that loads any `.so` files, could you show me how to? It seems not so many tutorials on how to set up OpenCV exist out there.

Comment: http://hujiaweibujidao.github.io/blog/2014/10/22/android-ndk-and-opencv-development-with-android-studio/